# How to specify exacts axis breaks in a map using sf and ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am making maps with `sf` and `ggplot2`. Is it possible to adjust the xaxis so I can:

1 - Precise the exact number of breaks I want (say 4 in this case)

2 - Make the first and last labels start right at the beginning and the end of the axis (i.e. no gap with the plot border)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(patchwork)

poly <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(
  country = c("Canada", "Belgium"),
  scale = "medium",
  returnclass = "sf"
)

make_plot <- function(poly) {
  bbox <- st_bbox(poly)

  xmin <- bbox[1]
  xmax <- bbox[3]

  xbreaks <- pretty(seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = 4), n = 4)

  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = poly) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(xmin, xmax), expand = FALSE)
}

p1 <- make_plot(poly[poly$name_en == "Canada", ])
p2 <- make_plot(poly[poly$name_en == "Belgium", ])

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The `st_bbox` in your function will be for a rectangle around all objects in the `poly` sf dataframe (here the points surround Belgium *and* Canada. And the `pretty` doesn't look like it will return exactly four numbers consistently.  From `?pretty`: `Compute a sequence of about n+1 equally spaced ‘round’ values...`

Comment: Humm, I am using the subsetted poly in the function, so bbox should use the extent of the passed object.

Comment: You're right! My mistake on the `st_bbox`. I still get too many numbers from `pretty` though. Think that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close.  You might want to adjust how the x-axis labels are displayed. Be careful though, people can be touchy about maps.

The `pretty` function wasn't consistently returning exactly four distinct numbers for the x-axis.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(patchwork)

poly <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(
  country = c("Canada", "Belgium"),
  scale = "medium",
  returnclass = "sf"
)

make_plot <- function(poly) {
  bbox <- st_bbox(poly)
  
  # rounding the xmin & xmax to 2 decimal places
  xmin <- bbox[1] %>% round(2)
  xmax <- bbox[3] %>% round(2)
  
  xbreaks <- seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = 4)
  
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = poly) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(xmin, xmax), expand = FALSE)
}

# had to change the subsetting, may be due to package version difference.
p1 <- make_plot(poly[poly$name == "Canada", ])
p2 <- make_plot(poly[poly$name == "Belgium", ])

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>