# pretty_breaks not working with geom_spatraster

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra, tidyterra

I am trying to use `scales::pretty_breaks` with `geom_spatraster` like

```
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

r1 <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r2 <- r1 

r <- c(r1, r2)

names(r) <- c("R1", "R2")

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = r) +
  facet_wrap(~lyr, ncol = 2)+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "transparent", name = "Elevation",
                       option = "viridis", direction = -1) +
  theme(text=element_text(family = "serif", size=15), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", angle = 90, hjust = 0.5))

p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 3))
```

which returns the following error

> Error in min(lon) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Not familiar with raster, so just a guess: axis are not continuous, there might be a way of setting breaks using `coord_sf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue on `ggplot2` side (see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4622, https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/5442 and
[How to specify exacts axis breaks in a map using sf and ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015290/how-to-specify-exacts-axis-breaks-in-a-map-using-sf-and-ggplot2)).

In the meantime [tidyterra FAQs](https://dieghernan.github.io/tidyterra/articles/faqs.html#axis-breaks) suggests an approach that I adapted a bit for your case:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.55
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

r1 <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra"))
r2 <- r1

r <- c(r1, r2)

names(r) <- c("R1", "R2")

# Plot
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = r) +
  facet_wrap(~lyr, ncol = 2) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(
    na.value = "transparent", name = "Elevation",
    option = "viridis", direction = -1
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", angle = 90, hjust = 0.5)
  )

p + ggtitle("Default breaks")
```

[image]

```r
# Get bounding box in EPSG 4326 
ext <- r %>%
  project("EPSG:4326", mask = TRUE) %>%
  ext() %>%
  as.vector()

# Include "manually" the breaks
p +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_pretty(n = 3)(ext[c("ymin", "ymax")])) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_pretty(n = 3)(ext[c("xmin", "xmax")])) +
  ggtitle("Custom breaks")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>